# Date Object Behaviour

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

In JavaScript,
Result of the Date Object is different when it comes to Different Time Zones and Different Notation.

eg.

```
var res= "2018-08"; 
var dat=new Date(res);
```

Result are :

```
Tue Jul 31 2018 22:00:00 GMT-0200 (West Greenland Summer Time)  for GMT-0200  Time Zone
```

and

```
 Wed Aug 01  2018 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

But When

```
var res= "2018/08";
```

We are getting same date

```
Wed Aug 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Wed Aug 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Atlantic Daylight Time)
```

Can Anyone Explain me Why its not Constant when we gave "-" as delimiter

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out…

Comment: Take a look at [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). Your first sentence pretty much sums up the answer.

Comment: please, specify in which browser you tried

Comment: @ManuelOrtiz I have Used Google Chrome Browser

Answer (score 1):

In order for the object to understand the format you're feeding it, is by actually telling it the format you're feeding it.

The below might help you achieve what you're after:

**Option 1:**

Using [date set methods](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods_set.asp) or using the [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) functionality (if that satisfies your needs).

**Option 2:**

Using something ott similar to [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) that will do the logic for you.

Comment: Yeah.It helps me to learn Date Object Behaviour.But,My Question is Why the date will change when I use "-" as delimiter and why not change of date won't happen when I use "/" as delimiter..

Comment: Because changing the character changes the locale. - Meaning, that for instance India might use 'mm-dd-yyyy' and US might use 'dd/mm/yyyy', and this is handled inside JavaScript. - You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Examples).